# Android Gradle file get values from .json file from application in library

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have an Android project with a few libraries (with apply plugin: 'com.android.library') and the main app (with apply plugin: 'com.android.application'). Is it possible to read something like this:

```
String[] myLinks = new JsonSlurper().parse(file("settingsFile.json")).myLinks
```

in separate library's .gradle file?
settingsFile.json in located in app folder (main application).

Thanks in advance!